# Wordpress exchange platform

Tags: development, trading, javascript, money-transfer, fiat

Hello from where I should start to built my own cryptocurrency exchange and Fiat/crypto exchange on wordpress? What steps I should take to built that kind of platform? I have some knowledge of javascript and wordpress.

Comment: I highly recommend to read andrew‘s post: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/71204/how-to-develop-own-bitcoin-web-wallet#comment82640_71204